# Does the DC-3 have a prop sync?

Tags: turboprop, multi-engine, dc-3

I'd like to ask if the DC-3 has a prop sync.
I found nothing about prop sync in the DC-3 operations manual, in the running specs, design features, or in the chapters about its engine and propeller. I've read the Wikipedia article about prop sync (which  didn't mention it) and this [What is propeller / engine sync and how does it work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/what-is-propeller-engine-sync-and-how-does-it-work) (which was great, but didn't speak of the DC-3). I've used this last link (which highlights the instrument) to check pictures of the cockpit and didn't see anything that looked exactly the same, but I don't think the instruments would look exactly the same in aircraft of different manufacturers (Junkers and Douglas). I assumed it didn't, but being that it's a twin-engine (which qualifies as a multi-engine) turboprop aircraft I'd have thought it'd make sense to have one. Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: The DC-3 has radial engines, the BT-67 is the turboprop version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Judging from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgxCRzqxXRs), it does not have an automatic prop sync. When throttles are advanced you can hear the harmonic beat of the twin propeller blades, and during the climb the instructor seems to manually set the levers to <s>reduce the harmonic</s> set the correct manifold pressure. He may or may not have an indicator to help him, but judging from the sound effects there is no automatic synching taking place.

And here is an old [C-47 cockpit procedure training film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA_N10PQtl0), on how to fly the aircraft. Nothing on synchronising the propellers.

That beautiful engine sound is not produced by a turbine by the way.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance. I thought propeller-driven meant the same as turboprop. I don't really understand much about airplanes. I'm trying my best though. it's all very conceptual when you are not a pilot or  a mechanic .  I've learnt about rules and lingo used by FAA and EASA and read plenty of manuals, but I never figured something apparently clear could have meant something so different. In my head anything that had a propeller would be a turboprop. I realise how daft that sounds but it's the truth anyway. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help, that's what we're here for.